# Access DoCmd.TransferText Specification Argument Location

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The following lines of code should export data from a query to a *.txt file, but results in an error.

```
strPath = "N:\apprais\targetDirectory\"
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "spcDataFile", "qryExportAppraisal", strPath & "DATAFILE.TXT"
```

[image]

Based on this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx, I don't think it should be necessary to have a Schema.ini file (unless it's a fixed-width file). Also when I executed the command in an older version of the application, I was able to export the data from the query to the *.txt file without the Schema.ini file.

Ultimately, I need to know if I'm correct about the Schema.ini, and if I am, is there a default location that specification files are saved to in Access 2010? I can't seem to find where it's defined. I've looked in External Data > Saved Imports/Exports, but am not able to find anything resembling `spcDataFile`

Comment: It is giving an error because you tell it there is an export specification, but I suspect you do not have one saved.  Try removing the "spcDataFile" parameter to the transfertext function.

Comment: Which might be the case. Is there a default location where export specifications are saved? I don't see anything in the latest version of the application, or previous versions (where the command was able to execute successfully).

Comment: If I change the specification argument, I get the following error:
3625 The text file specification "XXXXX" doesn't exist. You cannot import, export, or link using the specification.

Without the argument, I get the following error:
2522 The action or method requires a File Name argument

The second error seems odd. I would think there are overloads for the method, considering the argument is optional.

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue. Without specification argument, data outputs to file in the path string.

Comment: @June7, to clarify, did you not include the argument at all, or did you include the argument as an empty string? Also, what version of Access were you running?

Comment: Access 2010. No parameter in the argument, with and without empty string. Only thing I can think of that would cause failure is folder permissions. So I tried to a folder I don't have permission for and got error 3011 "... could not find object 'test#txt' ..."